# How to use texture as depth attachment?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, render-to-texture, depth-buffer, deferred-shading

I have a framebuffer with multiple render targets. All of them are textures and not renderbuffers. How can I use the `A` component of a `RGBA` texture as [depth attachment](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Object_Structure)? I want to use the default depth test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha is not a depth component. And only images who's formats have a depth component can be bound to `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`.

And before you ask, there is no RGB_DEPTH_COMPONENT format.

There's no reason you can't create a texture with `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24`.